How to list all installed monospace fonts in Windows?
There are many different ways to list all installed fonts.
But how can I list only all installed monospace fonts in Windows ?
The Windows Control Panel unfortunately doesn't provide this information in any column:

cross-references:

Similar question for Mac OS: How do I find all the monospace fonts in Font Book?
Same question but involving code work on stackoverflow.com:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417432/how-to-get-all-monospaced-fonts-in-windows
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72663767/generate-a-list-of-all-available-monospaced-fonts




python - Generate a list of all available monospaced fonts - Stack Overflow
